# Ошибка аутентификации в postgres после создания пользователя функцией и заданием числового пароля

Tags: postgresql

Создаю пользователя БД postgres функцией:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.create_databaseuser(
username name,
pass text)
RETURNS smallint
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
COST 100
VOLATILE STRICT SECURITY DEFINER PARALLEL UNSAFE
AS $BODY$
declare
begin
execute format('CREATE USER "%I" with password ''%I'' 
                LOGIN 
                NOSUPERUSER 
                INHERIT 
                NOCREATEDB 
                NOCREATEROLE 
                REPLICATION ;', username, pass);
return 1;
exception 
when others then
    return 0;
end;
$BODY$;
ALTER FUNCTION public.create_databaseuser(name, text)
OWNER TO postgres;
```

Вызываю функцию, задаю пароль цифрой:

```
SELECT public.create_databaseuser('sid',  '1');
```

При попытке подключиться пишет:

```
Server [localhost]: 192.168.1.10
Database [postgres]: bd1
Port [5432]:
Username [postgres]: sid
Пароль пользователя sid:
psql: сервер неожиданно закрыл соединение
Скорее всего сервер прекратил работу из-за сбоя
до или в процессе выполнения запроса.
Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .
```

но если указать пароль который начинается с буквы w1, например, все нормально.
Самое интересное, если исполнить строку

```
CREATE USER sid with password '1';
```

Все прекрасно работает. Я не правильно передаю значение пароля?

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9908335e8b1923fa511a4821db389b6e - ошибка очевидна.

Comment: Для меня все равно не очевидна ошибка, так как если передать '1' или '1w' резальтат один, а если передать 'w1' совсем другой.

Comment: Вы используете шаблон подстановки `%I`. Который, если верить документации, "`I` treats the argument value as an SQL identifier". А передаёте вы значение-литерал. Так что следует использовать шаблон именно для литералов. Либо самостоятельно квотировать все служебные символы и использовать шаблон для строк.

Comment: Спасибо за отличный ресурс и вашу помощь.

Answer (score 0):

```
execute format('CREATE USER ' || username || ' with password '''|| pass ||
                ''' LOGIN 
                NOSUPERUSER 
                INHERIT 
                NOCREATEDB 
                NOCREATEROLE 
                REPLICATION ;');
```

Comment: Стрёмно... введёт юзер в пароле кавычку или бэкслэш - и вот оно, счастье...

Comment: о, спасибо.. это я уже ограничу

Comment: Я бы всё же рекомендовал исходную форму - но при этом заменить оба шаблона на `%L`. Типа `execute format('CREATE USER %L with password %L ... REPLICATION ;', username, pass);`. Тогда сервер сам всё за-эскейпит

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]